# Can AnyDice.com handle weighted dice?

Tags: anydice, loaded-dice

Is it possible to weight the dice in AnyDice.com and then use like normal?

I'd like to use a standard d6, with values 1-6, but weighted such that the probability for rolling a specific value is as follows.

```
1: 18%
2: 18%
3: 19%
4: 18%
5: 17%
6: 10%
```

I'd then like to find the probability of

```
Xd6
Xd6 +Y
Xd6 +Y dropping lowest N
etc.
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. The Anydice documentation details how we can describe arbitrary dice. Functionally with percentages like that, the dice is equivalent to:

- 18 sides of value 1, 2 and 4.
- 19 sides of value 3.
- 17 sides of value 5.
- 10 sides of value 6.

... So we'll define exactly that die [in this Anydice program](http://anydice.com/program/fd69):

```
W: {
 1:18,
 2:18,
 3:19,
 4:18,
 5:17,
 6:10
}

output d6 \ for comparison \
output dW
```

[image: anydice output with correct percentages]

The syntax used there is **sequences**, and we're using it so we don't have to write out `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...` and so on eighteen times, and then the same for the five other faces. That's too prone to error and difficult to read. A more normal usage of sequences is writing `1..3:2`, which is a sequence from 1 to 3 repeated twice, which is to say it represents `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3`. We're generating a sequence that contains 1 repeated 18 times. The same goes for the other values.

W is a variable (covered in The Basics in the documentation). Variables must be uppercase, but you can name it whatever you want, including `WEIGHTED_DIE` if you'd prefer.

Comment: That's a bit more elegant than what I was writing out, so +1 for you :)

Comment: Great answer. I took the liberty of improving the anydice syntax. You don't have to provide ranges for every repeater.

Comment: @edgerunner Wow, that's impressive. Thanks very much for that. :)

Comment: When there's troubleyou call dW?

Comment: I read the documentation on sequences, but some how missed where it talked about this.  Also I don't know if I ever would've thought "19 sides of value 3" so that's awesome.  Thank you very much!